# Can i allocated more then 30gb to Ubuntu Wubi?

Tags: system-installation

Says it all the title!
I would like to use Linux/Ubuntu because of its Interface but i dont wont to lose windows all together!

Answer (score 2):

No. WUBI is a system to let you taste Ubuntu and the 30Gb limit is there due to various issues (stability being one).

Alternatives:

- install Ubuntu side by side.
- install Ubuntu and use Windows in a VirtualBox.
- use Ubuntu in a Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. [Here's a guide explaining how](http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.ie/2012/10/increasing-ubuntu-wubi-disk-image.html).

**Taken from the Link above:**

> Open up the wubi.exe file with 7ZIP, and extract the resize2fs.exe and
>   cygwin1.dll files from the bin directory to a convenient directory.
>   Then run the command
>
> resize2fs.exe -f d:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 70G
>
> Substitute d:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk with the location of your disk,
>   and change the 70G to the size that you want.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This site is not exactly a link farm, answers are supposed to be just that: answers, not a space to drop links (external information can change in time) Please add the gist of this solution to your answer, including the required commands.